# VMware ESXi 6 not reporting CPU usage correctly over SNMP

Tags: vmware-esxi, snmp

I'm trying to monitor CPU usage of VMware host over SNMP, and I'm not getting the result I expect. I'm requesting this resource with snmpwalk: `HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad` AKA `hrProcessorTable`. I get a list of CPU cores, and a number. I'm assuming % load. Averaging them out, I get 38% load. But when I compare to reported CPU load in vcenter, I get 65% load (on hosts list tab). I tried searching for OIDs on the web, but can't find anything more specific, so a lot is left for my interpretation.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a different OID I need to be looking at? Or am I not interpreting the number I get in SNMP correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not figure out how to use SNMP, but I got vSphere Perl SDK downloaded form vmware, and used CLI apps to access vCenter API to get CPU load numbers that match those reported in vCenter.